# RPi loses its wlan0 configuration when any Docker container is started

Tags: wireless, docker

Every time when I start a Docker container my RPi device loses it wireless board configuration. By configuration I mean that it loses its IP address, the DNS resolver and the gateway settings.

Because of that I can't connect to device on net, has anyone had a similar issue before?

```
# Before Docker container starts
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:a8:93:73  
          inet addr:192.168.0.20  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ada4:3dc4:b933:7a5b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:525 errors:0 dropped:19 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:411 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:558627 (545.5 KiB)  TX bytes:48299 (47.1 KiB)
```

```
# After Docker container starts
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:a8:93:73  
          inet6 addr: fe80::ada4:3dc4:b933:7a5b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5830 errors:0 dropped:19 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4087 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5743386 (5.4 MiB)  TX bytes:566484 (553.2 KiB)
```

Some notes:

- This happens with any container, not a specific one;
- To stop the issue I just need to stop all containers that are running.

Comment: @techraf I have added more info, hope it helps, please tell me if I should add something else.

Comment: i am having the same issue but i do know what is the solution. I stopped all the containers but this is did not solve the problem. still i wifi (wlan0) is not recognized in the stretch OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am facing the same issue, the Wi-Fi gets disconnected after starting one docker container.

The issue has been temporarily resolved by disabling the static IP.

1. Check the file - `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, make sure all the static IP mapped with wlan0/SSIDs are commented out.
2. Reboot the Raspberry Pi.
3. Start the container.

Hope it works for you too.

Comment: It's been a long time that I had this problem. I solved it by a workaround. I'll accept this as the answer, so, if someone else encounter the same problem, maybe it will help him.

Comment: I had the same issue. When I started any container, wifi just disappeared in rasbian. By removing the static ip from the dhcpcd.conf fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue,  and did not really understood the root cause but found a solution. It looks like DHCPC service failed to load once docker is running/started

You can check by running this, if Wireless is back to life it's likely the same issue I had

```
sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd
```

The clean fixed I did, was to edit the dhcpcd.service and adding a docker dependencies to wait for docker.service to run before dhcpcd service

it looks like

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service
```

then change the [Unit] block as below (by dropping the Before=network.target

```
[Unit]
Description=dhcpcd on all interfaces
Wants=network.target docker.service
After=docker.service
```

Comment: This answer safes me a lot of time. Problem occurs for me, after I running a `docker-compose` stack on my RPI 3B+. After a `reboot` my wpa-controller was not able to establish a connection. `After=docker.service` solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem cannot be reproduced given the information you provided and here's a minimal, working procedure to prove:

- start with a fresh [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) image on your Raspberry Pi 3
- login
- configure Wi-Fi interface (`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`)

  and connect to the network (assuming you get `192.168.0.20` from DHCP)
- install Docker:

  ```
    sudo curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh
  ```
- run container:

  ```
    sudo docker run -d -p 8080:80 lalyos/rpi-nginx
  ```
- check the connectivity (on `wlan0` interface) from another machine:

  ```
    curl 192.168.0.20:8080
  ```

It works, you should get a short HTML document response containing:

```
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
```

It means `wlan0` also works.

Comment: Well, this has started after I have fixed the IP address for the wifi board through the gui tool in Raspbian. If I connect the RPI through a cable connection, this issue don't happens at all.